# Transform css animations to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, packery

I'm stuck here.

How to I transform this:

```
 -webkit-transition:all 0.66s ease-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.66s ease-out;
-ms-transition:all 0.66s ease-out;
-o-transition:all 0.66s ease-out;
transition:all 0.66s ease-out;
```

into jQuery animations?
I'm using this script, to make an "onload" animation using Packery/Masonry that all items ease from the upper left corner to their positions.
Unforunately this css3 transition is causing a shaking with the packery script when you resize the browser. A solution would be to use jquery animations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> Unforunately this css3 transition is causing a shaking with the packery script when you resize the browser. <s>A solution would be to use jquery animations.</s>

Or remove the class that adds the transitions after the initial transitions took place.

Comment: This is a even better solution! I will try that out!

Comment: Do you know how to delay the removal?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#element').animate({top : 200, left: 200}, 660);
```

make sure `#element` has position relative OR absolute.

hope that helps.